# ZendFramework 2 - painfully slow?

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework2

I have installed the ZendSkelletonApp on my webserver, which runs with php-fpm (5.5+, so opcache is enabled) and apache.

However, response time is - for the out of the box example application - 110ms, which seems like a lot to me. A "static" php-file is served in ~30ms. I am not saying that this should be possible with a php framework looping through listeners and whatnot, but serving a static controller & template with > 100ms is really slow.

Even with generating class- and templatemaps ( http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/using-zendloaderautoloader/ ) and enabling module and configuration caching in the application.config.php , I couldn't get below the 100ms mark.

Are there any other ways of enhancing performance for zf2?

Comment: https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpSuperluminal reduced the request time to 95-99ms. That's better, but still 3 times of what a normal script execution needs.

Comment: Did you try the things described in this question, it usually helps a lot:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667621/zf2-optimize-for-high-traffic

Answer (score 3):

ZF2, due to its nature, has a lot of file-IO for every request. A single page load request to load a data set from a database with doctrine and display the results can result in the opening around 200 php files. (Run an xdebug cache grind and you can see how much time is spent checking for, and opening files. It can be substantial.)

Most of what's being opened is "small," and executes very quickly once it's been read off-disk, but the actual file-io itself can cause significant delays.

A couple things you need to go with a ZF2 app in PRODUCTION:

1) Run "composer dump-autoload -o" which will cache a full auto-load map for the vendor directory. This keeps the autoload system from having to run a "file_exists()" before including a needed file.

2) Generate an autoload classmap for your project itself and make sure the project is configured to use it.

3) Make sure you've set up a template map in your config so ZF2 doesn't have to "assume" the location of your templates, which results in disk IO.

4) Make sure you have an opcode caching solution in place such as Zend Opcache or APC (depending on your PHP version). You will want it set up to have a medium-term cache timeout (an hour or more), and file stat should be disabled in production. You should hard-clear this cache every time you deploy code (can be accomplished via apache restart, a script, etc).

5) If you're using anything that depends on Annotations, such as Doctrine, etc, you MUST make sure the annotations are cached. APC is a good solution for this, but even a file cache is much better than no cache at all. Parsing these annotations is very expensive.

This combination resulted in "instantaneous" page loads for ZF2 for me.

While developing, don't sweat it too much. Install opcode caching if you want, but make sure it will stat files to check if they're changed...otherwise it'll ignore changes you make to the files.

Comment: i use it but problem not sloved still high cpu usage