# Zend2 class loading in huge application

Tags: optimization, zend-framework2

I started work on a huge project build on Zend2 with Sceleton and Modular structure.

The project seems build professionally but with big performance issue (pages load for 15-30 sec).
Timing from `index.php` to Model.Controller.IndexAction is around 2 sec ...

I put a lot of research but couldn't find problem in the business logic.
It seems like  `include $file` and  `new $class` (repeated thousands of times ) create the overall slowness.

Any suggestion where to look at will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14672471/1208233

Comment: Can you provide more details about the files being included and classes being instantiated? You shouldn't ever need to use `include` in a ZF2 application, and if you think this is causing the slowness, you seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: What's the PHP version? Also [check out this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwpGPlL8oZc)