# Using ZF2 components without entire MVC process

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, components

How feasible is it to use the Zend Framework 2 components without using the MVC process? For example I love the forms / validation and ACL elements but am not sure if that is actually possible without the whole MVC system?

As a framework ZF2 is very slow (although I think its a very good system) so would like to encourage its use without the whole package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Zend Form component has a [separate repository](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zend-form) and it can be used in any application as a component with help of [composer](https://getcomposer.org/). (I'm assuming that you're using composer and your application also uses composer's autoloader) It requires only [InputFilter](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zend-inputfilter) and [Stdlib](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zend-stdlib) components.

You can try easily. Open your command line:

```
$ cd /path/to/an-empty-folder
```

Create a `composer.json` file with the content below

```
{
    "name": "Form Demo App",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "zendframework/zend-form": "2.3.*@dev"
    }
}
```

and after type

```
$ composer update
```

Following dependencies will be installed automatically into the `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` will be created :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.3.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.3.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-filter (2.3.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-inputfilter (2.3.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing zendframework/zend-form (2.3.3)
    Downloading: 100%
```

From performance viewpoint, ZF2 is not very slow. You just need to do [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14776994/199593) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14672471/199593) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16500533/199593) on production environment to run your application much more more performant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A couple of points - firstly I wouldn't be using composer so is it possible just using files / includes? Secondly thanks for the links. The issue with those points (not saying your links are bad!) is that any Opcaching will always help improve performance on a framework (however the other points about class mapping is interesting). Statistically whenever I see comparisons Zend generally comes out super slow (even though I think its a great framework) so in production we have purposefully held off using it. I think the problems are inherent with the framework.

Comment: There are lot of metrics exists to calculate overall software quailty like reliability, testability, maintainability, security, scalability, portability, development cost, usabilty etc... Not only efficiency. This is a tradeoff. ZF2, Symfony 2, Doctrine 2 all of them are good frameworks and libraries  with some tradeoffs. Your most important focus should not only performance if you're not writing a single page hello world app, never.